# drawing candle chart and line chart in combined chart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

i'm used VERSION 3.1.0 in [MPAndroidChart_GITHUB](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

i tried this code

activity_test.xml

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CandleStickChart
            android:id="@+id/lc_chart1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_graph"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.75"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.90">

</com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CandleStickChart>
```

activity.java

```
public void initChart() {
        chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        chart.setDragEnabled(true);
        chart.setPinchZoom(false);
        chart.setDrawBorders(false);    
        chart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(5);
        // enable scaling and dragging
        chart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        chart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true);
        chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        CandleData data = new CandleData();
        chart.setData(data);

        XAxis x = chart.getXAxis();
        x.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        x.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B8B8B8"));
        x.setDrawGridLines(false);
        x.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        x.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
        x.setEnabled(true); 

        YAxis ly = chart.getAxisLeft();
        ly.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B8B8B8"));
        ly.setLabelCount(10, false); //
        ly.setDrawGridLines(false);
        ly.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        ly.setAxisLineColor(Color.WHITE);
        YAxis ry = chart.getAxisRight();
        ry.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        ry.setEnabled(false); 
        
        chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
}
```

it's chart init and drawing

```
btn_start.setOnClickListener(new OnSingleClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSingleClick(View v) {
                ArrayList<CandleEntry> values = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    float multi = 15;
                    float val = (float) (Math.random() * 40) + multi;

                    float high = (float) (Math.random() * 9) + 8f;
                    float low = (float) (Math.random() * 9) + 8f;

                    float open = (float) (Math.random() * 6) + 1f;
                    float close = (float) (Math.random() * 6) + 1f;

                    boolean even = i % 2 == 0;

                    values.add(new CandleEntry(
                            i,
                            val + high,
                            val - low,
                            val,val
//                            even ? val + open : val - open,
//                            even ? val - close : val + close
                    ));
                }

                CandleDataSet set1 = new CandleDataSet(values, "Data Set");
                set1.setDrawIcons(false);
                set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
//        set1.setColor(Color.rgb(80, 80, 80));
                set1.setShadowColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                set1.setShadowWidth(0.7f);
                set1.setDrawValues(false);
//                set1.setDecreasingColor(Color.RED);
//                set1.setDecreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
//                set1.setIncreasingColor(Color.rgb(122, 242, 84));
//                set1.setIncreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
//                set1.setNeutralColor(Color.BLUE);
                //set1.setHighlightLineWidth(1f);

                CandleData data = new CandleData(set1);

                chart.setData(data);
                chart.invalidate();
            }
});
```

code is good working

[image: CandleStickChart]

but it's only CandleStickChart

i want candle and line in CombinedChart
i'm try change code

first, change file is layout xml

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart
            android:id="@+id/lc_chart1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_graph"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.75"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.90">

</com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart>
```

activity.java

```
public void initHeartChart() {
        chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        chart.setDragEnabled(true);
        chart.setPinchZoom(false);
        chart.setDrawBorders(false);

        chart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(5);
        // enable scaling and dragging
        chart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        chart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true);
        chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        CombinedData data = new CombinedData();
        chart.setData(data);

        XAxis x = chart.getXAxis();
        x.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        x.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B8B8B8"));
        x.setDrawGridLines(false);
        x.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        x.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
        x.setEnabled(true);

        YAxis ly = chart.getAxisLeft();
        ly.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B8B8B8"));
        ly.setLabelCount(10, false); //
        ly.setDrawGridLines(false);
        ly.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        ly.setAxisLineColor(Color.WHITE);
        YAxis ry = chart.getAxisRight();
        ry.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        ry.setEnabled(false); 

        chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
}
```

but it's so strange

first data is not see? ugly drawing??
sorry, i'm bad english...

[image: combined_candle]

it's draw candle in combined chart

but you can see first ugly data.

how to improve my code?

i need any help.

thanks you for read my document

Answer (score 1):

try to set space in xAxis

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setSpaceMin(barData.getBarWidth() / 2f);
xAxis.setSpaceMax(barData.getBarWidth() / 2f);
```

or set xAxis minimum to -0.5

```
xAxis.setAxisMinimum(-0.5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this code.

```
XAxis x = chart.getXAxis();
x.setAxisMinimum(data1.getXMin() - 0.5f);
x.setAxisMaximum(data1.getXMax() + 0.2f);
```

[image: chart]

thanks for aiwiguna and i hope to others helps, too